# Can Karpenter target only specific node groups in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling, karpenter

I have been setting up karpenter in my test eks cluster. And what I have noticed is that Karpenter works on a cluster-level --- it monitors every node and pod in the cluster and scales them up and down. However, I am wondering if it is possible to tell karpenter to target/monitor only specific node groups in the cluster with labels/tags and stuff? Because I feel it is a bit risky to apply it to the whole cluster in my company's infrastructure and would like to start with a smaller target.

Thanks in advance!

Any thoughts on karpenter targeting a specific node group.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that simply by adding labels to your `Provisioner` custom resource, just like the current node groups. For example:

```
labels:
  nodegroup: frontend
```

Karpenter will not affect existing nodes (you'll have to scale down yourself).